# Customize multiple banner components separately in Spartacus

Tags: javascript, angular, spartacus-storefront

I have multiple bannercomponents in my home page and need to customise each one independently. I understand I can use ConfigModule.withConfig to replace the bannercomponent with a customcomponent but that will replace all bannercomponents with the same customcomponent. Is there a way to replace each of the bannercomponents separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define custom banner components in backoffice/sampledata based on the original one, then just add cms mapping in your Spartacus for each one separately:

```
     cmsComponents: {
       BannerComponent: {
          component: YourBannerComponent,
       },
       YourOtherBannerComponent: {
          component: YourOtherBannerComponent,
       },
     },
```